# How to modify elements in a page using location.href?

Tags: javascript, html, url, dom

I'm using location.href to get the URL of the current page.

Below is a snippet from my JavaScript code :

```
 <script>

   var url = location.href();

    /*code to modify the elements in the page
     -------------------
     -------------------
    */

</script>
```

Now how can I modify this page's elements by using that varaible 'url'.
I know to use HTMLDOM. But something like document.getElementbyId() ... would refer to the current page in which I'm writing my script, but how can I make it refer to the page in variable 'url'.

Or is there any way to modify elements of the current page without getting it's url??

Thanks

Comment: You better take a look to JavaScript, i think you didn't understand it at all, you don't need any url to modify elements of the current page, where did you get this information from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS will always refer to the page in which you're running the script. This means that if the same script is included in several pages, it will run accordingly to each. You don't need to know current's page url to perform any DOM manipulation.

The only exception to this is when you're dealing with frames. For that case there are ways to address a frame content from the main page.